# Summary statistics from aggregated groups using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, summarize

I have a dataset with this structure:

```
library(data.table)    
dt <- data.table(
  record=c(1:20),
  area=rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(4, 6, 3, 7)), 
  score=c(1,1:3,2:3,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1:3),
  cluster=c("X", "Y", "Z")[c(1,1:3,3,2,1,1:3,1,1:3,3,3,3,1:3)]
)
```

I would like to aggregate the data so I can identify the most common cluster in each area for a given score (for example 1). I would also like some basic frequencies and percentages to be calculated with an output looking something like this:

```
dt_summary_for_1_score <- data.table(
  area=c("A","B","C","D"),
  cluster_mode=c("X","X","X","Z"),
  cluster_pct = c(100,66.6,100,80),
  cluster_freq = c(2,2,1,4),
  record_freq = c(2,3,1,5)
)
```

Ideally I would like a solution that uses `data.table`. Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any searching on SO? Surely there have been examples of using the aggregate function with data.table objects? If you have done searching an are having difficulty with applying the answers, you should cite instance and state where those difficulties are occurring

Comment: It's not clear where `cluster_pct`, `cluster_freq` and `record_freq` come from

Comment: They are the outputs I would like. So it you subsetted the data.table so only scores of 1 are present the values would relate to them

Comment: I have also searched on SO to try and find an answer and while there are examples that do something similar, there is nothing this specific that I can reengineer for my own purposes

Comment: what to do in case of ties

Comment: In case of ties then return only one of the results and associated summary stats (in the actual data a tie is very unlikely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leverage `frank`, though a solution with `sort(table(cluster))` is possible as well.

```
dt_summary = 
  dt[ , .N, keyby = .(area, score, cluster)
      ][ , {
        idx = frank(-N, ties.method = 'min') == 1
        NN = sum(N)
        .(
          cluster_mode = cluster[idx],
          cluster_pct = 100*N[idx]/NN,
          cluster_freq = N[idx],
          record_freq = NN
        )
      }, by = .(area, score)]
```

To get the example with `score == 1` we can subset this:

```
dt_summary[score == 1]
#    area score cluster_mode cluster_pct cluster_freq record_freq
# 1:    A     1            X   100.00000            2           2
# 2:    B     1            X    66.66667            2           3
# 3:    C     1            X   100.00000            1           1
# 4:    D     1            Z    80.00000            4           5
```

This returns different *rows* in the case of ties. You might try something like `cluster_mode = paste(cluster[idx], collapse = '|')` or `cluster_mode = list(cluster[idx])` instead for alternatives.

Breaking down the logic:

```
# Count how many times each cluster shows up with each area/score
dt[ , .N, keyby = .(area, score, cluster)
   ][ , {

    # Rank each cluster's count within each area/score & take the top;
    #   ties.method = 'min' guarantees that if there's
    #   a tie for "winner", _both_ will get rank 1
    #   (by default, ties.method = 'average')
    # Note that it is slightly inefficient to negate N
    #   in order to sort in descending order, especially
    #   if there are a large number of groups. We could
    #   either vectorize negation by using -.N in the 
    #   previous step or by using frankv (a lower-level
    #   version of frank) which has an 'order' argument
    idx = frank(-N, ties.method = 'min') == 1

    # calculate here since it's used twice
    NN = sum(N)

    .(
      # use [idx] to subset and make sure there are
      #   only as many rows on output as there are
      #   top-ranked clusters for this area/score
      cluster_mode = cluster[idx],
      cluster_pct = 100*N[idx]/NN,
      cluster_freq = N[idx],
      record_freq = NN
    )
  }, by = .(area, score)]
```